# Get Last Record From Each Month in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

> MongoDB
>
> shell version: 3.0.12

I have last 5 year record in my database, and each month has many records by date, want to find last record from each month for 1 year.

Thanks

Comment: Would suggest to augment your question with some sample documents and your expected output from that sample.

Comment: please provide sample record

Comment: pl check this out https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/